# Prefix tree слепок изменений

Tags: алгоритм, коллекции

Имея большое префиксное дерево (около 300мег.), как можно быстро получить уникальный хеш всего дерева после точечного изменения ? Как можно сделать уникальный слепок (SHA3 например) всего дерева ?

Answer (score 1):

У меня есть такая идея: что именно мы будем хешировать - не сильно принципиально, это фактически какой-то набор байт. Для простоты будем считать, что дерево не динамическое, а упаковано в массив (чтобы бы непрерывность данных). Можно сделать и без этого.

После этого любой стандартный алгоритм хеширования применить не тяжело (передаём сырой массив данных, оно будет захешированно).

Теперь о первом вопросе. Обычно хеши специально сконструированы чтобы затруднить подобную операцию. Но можно использовать серию полиномиальных хешей. Они не сильно надёжно, но это можно компенсировать их количеством.

Полиномиальный хеш вычисляется примерно так:

```
for (char x : _data)
      hash = (hash * BASE + (size_t)x ) % MOD;
```

Где BASE и MOD - параметры хеша.

Преимущество именно этого хеша в вашей задачи в том, что его можно "разрезать".
Пусть мы поменяли элемент в `_data[K]`. Тогда новый хеш будет равен `(old_hash + (new_data[K] - old_data[K]) * BASE ^ (data_size - K - 1) ) % MOD` Чтобы его быстро вычислить, достаточно иметь массив предпросчитанных значений `Pow[K] = Pow[K-1] * BASE % MOD` тогда любое изменение можно сделать за O(1). Время на предпросчёт будет не больше чем на начальное вычисление хеша.

Это скорее субъективный ответ, вохможно есть более удобные и надёжные способы.